# Query returns no output

Tags: php, sql-server, iis-7

Okay i am stumped as to what is wrong here. The page connects to the database correctly  but i don't get any output from my query.I use IIS,Windows 2012 SQL 2012 and PHP

```
<?php
  $serverName = "localhost"; 
  $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"BAR", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"password");
  $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
  if ($conn === false) {
        echo "Could not connect.\n";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  } else {
        echo "Connection created";
  }

  $query = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress FROM  Employees ";


  //execute the SQL query and return records
  $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

  while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<li>" . $row["FirstName"] . $row["LastName"] . $row["EmailAddress"] ."</li>";
  }

 sqlsrv_close();
 ?>
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($result)` show?  If it is false, then there is an issue with your select statement

Comment: What does `var_dump($result)` output?

Comment: whats your employees table look like?

Comment: Maybe there is a logon trigger that doesn't like it when you connect as `sa`...

Comment: When I add var_dump($result) it gives http500 error

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<li>" . $row["FirstName"] . $row["LastName"] . $row["EmailAddress"] ."</li>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ever get any situations like this where you're not getting any results when you expect there to be, it's worth checking for errors and printing them out.

Add this before your `where`:

```
if( $result === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

This will check if there's an issue with `$result`, and print out the errors for you to read over.

Comment: Thanks Duellsy that helped. Turns out I had misspelt one of my coulmns  in the query

Comment: no worries, you should mark answer as correct for future users